# How to set the accelerometer offset for all devices?

Tags: android, accelerometer, screen-resolution

I am trying to set an offset which is dependent on hardware of the device. By far now I have used getMaximmumRange and getResolution. But for each device I cant set the offset properly. Its not giving me stable results.

I have to capture the sensitivity of the device and then set an offset above which the shaking will be captured and their avg is set as an offset.

if anyone having more feasible solution, please answer.

Comment: I'm confused: what does the screen have to do with accelerometer offsets? If nothing, please remove that portion, otherwise please elaborate on their relationship.

Comment: The reference here is about the resolution of Sensor in this case accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the resolution and then density.

I have set the range of resolution and then set the offset accordingly.

For devices with XHDPI screens I have added a margin to this offset as high-resolution devices are powerful.

So far its working for me.